# How do I save an WebView state?

Tags: android, webview

I am developing Android Application using HTML5. In my application there is one main HTML page and from that page i am opening the pop up page. But when orientation change pop up page is closed down.

I want to open that pop up page when orientation change

Thanks in Advance

Comment: want to open pop up page or want to make it remain open even orientation change?

Comment: use `android:configChanges="orientation"` in activity tag in manifest...

Comment: i did android:configChanges="orientation" in activity tag in manifest file but no change  and yes i want to remain open even orientation change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the screen orientation changes the activity starts again. so in your activity on create method is calling again, that's  why the pop is getting closed. you have to know about SingleInstence concept in Android. by using SingleInstence we can prevent the recreation of object while orientation changed and you can notify the orientation change by using onConfigurationChanged override method in your activity class.
If you application is in Html then prefer phonegap..